# How to ignore a search field in a Doctrine/Mongo QueryBuilder search?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Mongo ODM query used to search and one of the fields (Property Type) has a "All" value whereby the search should ignore the rest of the values.

```
$query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('SomeBundle:Listing')
     ->select('id', 'title','saleOrRent')
     ->field('residentialOrCommercial')->equals($residentialOrCommercial)
     ->field('propertyType')->equals($propertyType)
     ->getQuery();
```

I can do exact text matches however when someone selects "All" on the propertyType how do I account for in the query above? I mean when someone selects "All" i want the query to totally ignore the "propertyType" field and bring back all values.

I know I am not being super clear but I am trying to be.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('SomeBundle:Listing')
     ->select('id', 'title','saleOrRent')
     ->field('residentialOrCommercial')->equals($residentialOrCommercial);

if ($propertyType != 'All') {
     $qb->field('propertyType')->equals($propertyType);
}

$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: thank you sooooo much for helping me with this tip. I truly appreciate it.